# How to paste code and not have it formatted in Blogger?

Tags: blogger

I'm trying to paste some example XML snippets into a blog post on blogger, but every time I save or preview the post, blogger seems to remove my XML tags and just display the parameters. I can't find a way of retaining code, there is no "code" button on the WYSIWYG editor

For example,

```
<MyTag>
 <myValue>some value</myValue>
</MyTag>
```

Becomes

```
some value
```

I've tried to surround it with the pre tag but that doesn't work either

Any ideas? I'd rather not have to screenshot code as that rules out copy/pasting in the future

Answer (score 7):

I've been using [tohtml](http://tohtml.com/) to format code for a while, and I just tested its output with blogger and it works.  It will even give you syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 2):

`&lt;` and `&gt` should go in place of the angle brackets.

This isn't an issue with blogger, rather your web browser interpreting the <>s as tags, and so not displaying them. `&lt; and &gt;` mean < and >, respectively, to your web browser.

Comment: Thanks Phoshi, I was considering using that but didn't like the idea of doing that over a 50+ line snippet of code ;)

Comment: Ouch! You could try a find&replace, I suppose? :P

Answer (score 2):

Copy and paste source code onto: http://formatmysourcecode.blogspot.com/

It replaces any non-alphanumeric characters in your text, so you can then copy/paste it into your blog

Answer (score 1):

You can also paste your code to [gist](https://gist.github.com/) and a pretty link is available to display gist code in your blog, for example :

```
<script src="https://gist.github.com/Ameausoone/4714699.js"></script>
```